# php building a mySQL query with a wildcard

Tags: mysql, wildcard

Cant seem to figure out whats wrong, the query should be correct, and it works in phpMyAdmin but when I introduce a wildcard into the php string "%", every query fails.

This works:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT `id`FROM `table`WHERE `name` LIKE '".$resources[1]."'", 
                                                                   mysql_real_escape_string($resources[1]));
```

This does not:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT `id`FROM `table`WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$resources[1]."%'", 
                                                                   mysql_real_escape_string($resources[1]));
```

The query Im obviously trying to generate is

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table`WHERE `name` LIKE '%someName%'
```

Comment: What does `echo $query;` tell you? Can you make an example of that kind of value you are searching? Don't forget that a leading `%` requires that there be something in front of the value, so searching for `%Michael%` will *not* give you `MichaelTaylor`

Comment: it doesnt generate at all when I introduce the wildcard, without the wildcard it generates as it should

Comment: You mean `$query` is empty in the second example? That seems unlikely.

Comment: I agree with you but that is what is happening, and the only difference is when I introduce the wildcard, when the wildcard is absent, echo $query comes out as it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the sprintf man page: http://php.net/sprintf

```
$sql = sprintf('..... '%%%s%%', $var);
                       ^^--- turns into %
                         ^--  %s -> $var
                           ^^-- turns into %
```

Your code, as written, does NOTHING to prevent sql injection, since you're not using sprintf() properly.

Comment: SQL injection is already protected against elsewhere in the code, that isnt what I was asking about.

Comment: However you are correct that I wasnt using sprintf properly and that was what was causing the problem